# Casting from superclass to subclass fail in unit test (mockito)

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, mockito, downcast

I thought I know the basic idea of upcast & downcast, but this problem I encountered make me think again.

Currently, it compiled and work flawlessly. But when I try to do the unit test (by using mockito), it keeps pointing that my way of casting has issues.

I've tested every single possible solution that I can make up with, but none of it satisfies this mockito platform.

To make it clear, I've make a simplified version for my Superclass and Subclass as below:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
  private String A;
  private String B;

  protected Parent(){
  }
// below are necessary getter setter n mapped column
...
}
--------------------------------
@Entity
public class Child extends Parent{
  private String C;
  private String D;

  protected Child(){
     super();
  }
// below are necessary getter setter n mapped column
...
}
---------------------------------
```

So above are two class that I will be using for downcasting and the class which will do such action as below:

```
public class People{
   public void CheckRelation(){
      Parent parent = new Child();
      parent = parentRepo(...); // to get some data
      Child child = (Child) parent;
   }
}
```

From what I know, that's the proper method to do downcasting, but I've got an issue with `Parent parent = new Child();` that give an error of `The constructor Child() is not visible` by mockito

Since I can't make any change toward `class Parent`, so I went to change `class Child()` constructor from protected to public (which I know not a wise move and shall not be done).

This later result in an error of :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Parent cannot be cast Child

Class `Child` was created to add additional functions for `Parent` as it can't be altered anymore. So `Child` was used as a medium to handle specifics amount of data and that's why it's necessary to downcast `Parent` to `child`.

Even though compile wise it worked fine, I believe this mockito error due to java runtime is it? Or is it due to something else?

Appreciate any wise answer from everyone and thank you

Comment: You set `parent` to a new `Child` then immediate overwrite it. If `parentRepo` returns a `Parent` there's no guarantee it can be cast to a `Child`. Not every problem is best solved (or solvable) by inheritance.

Comment: I suspect the same thing too, but can't think of any other workaround. Fyi, ```parentRepo``` will return ```Parent```